# Creating Markup Extension with Converter

Tags: c#, wpf, converters, markup-extensions

I'm trying to create a Markup Extension that will take a string of HTML, convert it to a FlowDocument, and return the FlowDocument. I'm fairly new to creating Markup Extensions and I'm hoping this will be obvious to someone with more experience. Here is my code:

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(FlowDocument))]
public class HtmlToXamlExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public HtmlToXamlExtension(String source)
    {
        this.Source = source;
    }

    [ConstructorArgument("source")]
    public String Source { get; set; }

    public Type LocalizationResourceType { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (this.Source == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Source must be set.");
        }

        FlowDocument flowDocument = new FlowDocument();
        flowDocument.PagePadding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        string xaml = HtmlToXamlConverter.ConvertHtmlToXaml(Source.ToString(), false);

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream((new ASCIIEncoding()).GetBytes(xaml)))
        {
            TextRange text = new TextRange(flowDocument.ContentStart, flowDocument.ContentEnd);
            text.Load(stream, DataFormats.Xaml);
        }

        return flowDocument;
    }
}
```

Update: Here is the XAML.

```
<RadioButton.ToolTip>
    <FlowDocumentScrollViewer Document="{ext:HtmlToXaml Source={x:Static res:ExtrudeXaml.RadioButtonCreateBody_TooltipContent}}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
</RadioButton.ToolTip>
```

And my VS error list:

- Error    3   Unknown property 'Source' for type 'MS.Internal.Markup.MarkupExtensionParser+UnknownMarkupExtension' encountered while parsing a Markup Extension. Line 89 Position 49.
- Error    1   The type "HtmlToXamlExtension" does not include a constructor that has the specified number of arguments.
- Error    2   No constructor for type 'HtmlToXamlExtension' has 0 parameters.

Comment: Can you post relevant XAML as well please?

Comment: And what is the question? Is anything not working?

Comment: Errors 1 and 2 seem to be pretty obvious. Just add a default constructor. Then Error 3 is perhaps only a follow-up.

Comment: Try Removing the constructor altogether; Anyway, your Source property has a public setter.

Comment: @sthotakura That's even better.

Comment: @sthotakura Removing the constructor worked like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You implemented you MarkupExtension without default constructor:
So you have 2 options:

1. Delete your specific constructor (Anyway you set `Source`
   directly)
2. Change invocation of you `HtmlToXamlExtension` if you remove `Source=` part, then Wpf will try to find constructor matching all unnamed fields right after `ext:HtmlToXaml` part:

   ```
   <RadioButton.ToolTip>
     <FlowDocumentScrollViewer 
            Document="{ext:HtmlToXaml {x:Static res:ExtrudeXaml.RadioButtonCreateBody_TooltipContent}}" 
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
   </RadioButton.ToolTip>
   ```

   **UPD:** Even though it works, but MSDN says, that [you should have default constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx#naming_the_support_type)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should create default constructor for your markup extension, and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It helped to me to install the .NET 4.7 (Developer Pack), I've seen this bug at .NET 4.6 but after upgrading it's gone.